# Writing on shared variable by acquiring mutex in shared mode(instead in exclusive mode)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

The usual pattern of using std::shared_timed_mutex is to let the 'reader' thread acquire it in shared mode and the 'writer' thread acquires it in exclusive mode. In this manner, the reads and writes cannot happen at the same time and thus the program is free from data-race/undefined behavior.

I wanted to understand if at all there's **any** problem if I change the mode among the threads i.e. the reader thread reads the shared variable after acquiring the lock in **exclusive mode** and the writer thread writes in the shared variable after taking the mutex in **shared mode**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <shared_mutex>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::shared_timed_mutex lck;
int shared_array[5];

void writerFunc(int index);
void readerFunc();

//main thread
int main() {
  std::thread writer_threads[5];
  for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    writer_threads[i] = std::thread(writerFunc,i);
  }

  while(true) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    readerFunc();
  }


  for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    writer_threads[i].join();
  }

}

//function executed in writer threads.
//Each writer thread will work on it's own index in the global shared array.
void writerFunc(int index) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 42.0);

  while(true) {
    {
      std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> sl(lck);

      //Writing random number in shared variable.
      shared_array[index] += dist(mt);
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
  }
}

//function executed in reader thread(main).
void readerFunc() {
  std::lock_guard<std::shared_timed_mutex> sl(lck);
  for(int i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    std::cout<<"\nshared_array["<<i<<"]--> "<<shared_array[i];
  }
  std::cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

Since the reader and writer thread cannot concurrently access the variable at the same time, therefore, there's no data race in the above program. Thread-sanitiser also does not report any problem with the above program.

I'm mainly having a little doubt regarding the values read by the reader thread.

Is it guaranteed by the C++ standard, irrespective of the underlying CPU architecture, that

a) the above program doesn't have any UB?

b) the reader thread can only see the latest value written by the writer thread?

******* **Additional details** ********

Please note that the above was a short sample program where I've tried to replicate a specific part of the design of my main project. Over there the scale is a lot bigger. e.g. the size of the array(not exactly an array but very similar) over there is ~2 million. Also the data structure is not a simple int but a custom serializable structure.

so think of something like this:

```
custom_serializable_struct shared_variable[2000000];
```

In my main program, there will be **'N' writer threads** and a **single reader thread**. Most of the time, writer threads will be working. Since N is a lot smaller than 2 million therefore I'm using separate synchronisation(1 std::atomic_flag for each of the 2 million indexes. This is used after acquiring the shared_timed_mutex) among the writer threads(I had omitted this aspect from the design of the sample code as I felt it was not relevant to what I was asking).

Like I've said above, most of the time, writer threads will be working. Only occasionally, the reader thread will work.

> Mainly, the program has following requirements:
>
> 1. I've to minimize the wait time of writer threads spent on the mutex while the reader thread is working.
> 2. I've to ensure that the reader thread, whenever it works, always gets the latest value written by the writer threads.

So basically this is what is happening in my main program:

**N writer threads:**

```
while (true) {
// 1. Acquire the shared_timed_mutex in shared mode.
// 2. Acquire the std::atomic_flag of the index, i, on which the thread has to work. This is required, as I mentioned, to prevent data race among writer threads.
// 3. Do changes in the custom_serializable_struct shared_variable[i]
}
```

**1 reader thread:**

```
while(true) {
// 1. long sleep time.
// 2. Acquire the shared_timed_mutex in exclusive mode.
// 3. read the entire 2 million values. Please note that this read is not done 1 by 1 like in a for loop. It's more like memcpy of the entire memory.
}
```

Comment: If the writer-thread has acquired only a shared-lock and writes to the shared data, then you’ll have a race condition against any other thread that has only a shared-lock and is reading.  (If your only other thread always gets an exclusive-lock, there’s no race, but then why bother with a read/write lock in the first place, when a simple mutex would do, and be less confusing to the human reader of the code?)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner in the sample program above, there's a single writer thread per index of the shared array. I couldn't have used a single std::mutex here because I didn't want any contention between the writer threads. One way for doing that which I can think of is to use separate std::mutex for each index, but let's just say that I don't want to use so many mutexes.

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry but I didn't get your point. True, there are multiple(5) writer threads in the program I've shared. But why do you say there's a contention when each one is writing only on their own index?

Comment: (a) This program has UB. (b) This question is meaningless because of (a).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. can you point to the undefined behavior?  That would help determine if the undefined behavior is central to the question, or an unrelated coding error that can be fixed in order to make the question meaningful.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. is there a UB because of a data race or some other reason? Because I don't see any data race here. Neither did the thread-sanitiser. If there's a UB because of some other violation, please do let me know what exactly?

Comment: @NicolBolas Each of the 5 elements of the array is a separate memory location. No two writer threads ever touch the same memory location.

Comment: Mutexes do more than just lock threads out of critical sections. They also establish [_memory barriers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier), of which, on some architectures, there may be more than one kind. I don't know this for fact, but it seems possible that the particular memory barrier instruction(s) executed when a thread acquires the lock in "shared" mode potentially could provide insufficient synchronization to a thread that is going to _write_ shared variables. And likewise, the exclusive lock could be wrong for a thread that is going to read what another thread wrote.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see any UB or data race in the program shown. The reader should observe the value written immediately before `unlock_shared()` on the writer thread that immediately preceded the `lock()` call on the reader thread in the mutex's global modification order; since that write happens-before the read.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `rand()` <-- right here.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Yeah, I don't really think those were key parts of the question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for pointing that out. I've tried to fix it.

Comment: Now it seems to be data race free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unlock_shared` [explicitly synchronizes with subsequent `lock` calls on the same mutex](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.sharedmutex.requirements#15). This would allow the reader to read data written by any of the writers. Similarly, `lock_shared` synchronizes with prior calls to `unlock`. So it is possible to use a `shared_mutex` backwards without a data race (note: `rand` is not required to be thread-safe).

But... should you?

The purpose of a mutex is to ensure data integrity, not just at the level of bytes (ie: data races), but at a higher level. You have 5 threads writing to 5 different locations. But... what is the *meaning* of the data? Are these data completely distinct from one another, or does the collection of data have some meaning that needs to be preserved? That is, if one thread writes to one value, does the reader get malformed information if another thread hasn't written its value yet?

If these data values are all completely, fundamentally separate, then a mutex is unnecessary (at least for basic types). What you're really doing is just atomic writes. The writers can write to an `atomic<T>`, and the reader will read these. Since the values are all disparate and lack any question of ordering between them, you don't need to block *any* thread from writing. All you need to do is ensure data integrity at the level of an individual `T`. Lock-free atomics will be much faster than any mutex-based solution.

But if the data has some notion of integrity to it, if the group of threads is collectively creating a single value that the reader thread should read in its entirety, then what you're looking for [is a `barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier), not a mutex. This object allows you to see if a group of execution agents have collectively reached a certain point. And if they have, it is safe for you to read the data. And once you're finished reading it, it is safe to release the agents to write to them once again.

Comment: In my use case(the one which I've tried to replicate in the shared sample), the data values are fundamentally separate. However I cannot use std::atomic like you suggested because the shared object is a custom serializable data-structure created to be sent over the network.

Comment: @VishalSharma If these are not simple objects, just associate a mutex with each separate object.  That'll scale even better if scalability is a concern.  And if scalability isn't a concern, it's not likely the extra memory overhead (likely very slight anyway, but still...) will matter at all.  The code becomes simpler because you don't have a shared mutex - you might even want to put the mutex in the object itself and encapsulate all accesses.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've added some reasoning behind the design at the end of the question.

Answer (score 3):

## But Why?

I am wondering what the motivation behind changing the roles of the reader and the writer with respect to locking may be! What problem are you solving by doing so?

In a previous comment, you mentioned that you do not want contention between writers.

Looking at the code, I infer also that the update of every `int` in the array is independent of the others but the reader *MUST* see them all at once as if collectively they have *ONE* meaning (the reason for exclusive lock). You have not mentioned this yet - so assuming this is ***not the intention***.

There is just one reader but many writers i.e. it looks inverted to a (some?) stereotypical case of having more readers than writers. This shouldn't be a major consideration.

Conveying an unintended meaning and surprising code should be avoided. I agree with @Nicol Bolas & suggest another approach too:

## Wrong Tool - use `std::atomic` instead

The inverted use of `std::shared_timed_mutex` is a surprise here for the future maintainer (yourself?). Plus, using it is the source of misleading message to the reader and the reason for this question.
I agree with @Nicol Bolas that atomic would solve this problem:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> shared_array[5];

void writerFunc(int index) {
   ///Other code
    while(true) {
        //Writing random number in shared variable.
        shared_array[index].fetch_add(dist(mt));

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
}

void readerFunc() {
    for (auto& item : shared_array) {
        std::cout << item;
    }
}
```

## Better Abstraction - use `libguarded::shared_guarded`

The root of the sorrow looks to be the level at which you have applied the `std::shared_timed_mutex lck` - it controls the *entire array* whereas you wish to have a finer control on *every element*.

I highly recommend you consider using the [`shared_guarded`](https://github.com/copperspice/cs_libguarded/blob/master/src/cs_shared_guarded.h) of the [cs_libguarded](https://github.com/copperspice/cs_libguarded) available under BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License.

```cpp
libguarded::shared_guarded<int> shared_array[5];  //Nailed it!

void writeFunc(int index) {
    //Other code
    while (true) {
        {
            auto handle = shared_array[index].lock();
            auto& item = *handle;
            item += dist(mt);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
}

void readerFunc() {
    for (auto& array_element : shared_array) {
        auto item = array_element.lock_shared();
        std::cout << *item;
    }
}
```

The above not only ensures the correct, unsurprising use of the shared data but also ensures *const correctness* as it does not allow writes on `lock_shared`. This can work with any data-types, not just `int`s - a restriction that `std::atomic` has. As @Solomon Slow points out, the memory barriers may cause unintended results with out-of-order execution with your original approach - this code doesn't have that problem. `libguarded` also ensures that access to shared data is always with the *correct synchronization* - no accidental use of shared data.

FYI, `shared_guarded` is equivalent to using a mutex for every element (as below), only much **cleaner, const correct and fool-proof**.

```cpp
std::shared_timed_mutex lck[5];  //Don't do it by hand, better use libguarded, as above
int shared_array[5];
```

I strongly recommend prioritizing cleaner implementation over arbitrary objectives like not wanting to have many `mutex`es. If you do not want contention please eliminate sharing instead of aiming to reduce mutexes. **The problem is sharing and not the existence of mutex**.

P.S.: You tagged the question as C++14 while libguarded needs C++17. As far as I checked, `libguarded::shared_guarded` should work with `std::shared_timed_mutex`.

Comment: I've added some reasoning behind the design at the end of the question.

Comment: I agree that the current design, specially the choice of the mode in which the locks are currently being acquired is surprising, to say the least. However, a major design overhaul is not going to happen anytime soon and that's why I'm more concerned only about the correctness of the current design. At the moment that's what matters.